# Importing XCPlayground module in Swift REPL

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm on OS X 10.10.2 and Xcode 6.1.1.  I'd like to import the XCPlayground module so I can test using the NSURLSession module (make an HTTP GET request).

When I run the Swift REPL via: `swift` then run `import XCPlayground` I get the following error: 
`repl.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'XCPlayground'`

Note that I can `import Foundation` without any errors.

Is this normal?  If so, how can I import XCPlayground successfully?  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of looking into the actual documentation, I know that Swift playgrounds are not as flexible as you might think. You can't easily import any framework/lib, but a few are included, such as Foundation.

There are tools/plugins around this, for example: [BBUToyUnboxing](https://github.com/neonichu/BBUToyUnboxing) claims to solve this for you. I haven't used it.

I recommend installing [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/) to manage Xcode plugins if you haven't already - it makes life better.

Side note: if you're looking into handling http in swift, I recommend [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) - I've enjoyed it in my most recent project.

EDIT: having just read the first bit of the BBUToyUnboxing README, this should be supported if you structure your project accordingly – see [the example they link to](https://github.com/neonichu/ContentfulDeliveryAPIFramework/tree/master/Playgrounds/SmallContentfulPlayground.playground).